# How can you change to color of the text in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

So, Im new to flutter and wanted to see how can you change the color of the text.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(new Hello());

class Hello extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new MaterialApp(
      home: new Material(
        child: new Center(
          child: new Text("Hello!"),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

this is a basic hello text and I want the text to be other color than the standard.

Comment: You want to change only that one `Text` widget or all text in your app?

Answer (score 1):

This can be easily achieved by style function. Which will take the `TextStyle` parameter, where you can specify color. You can use a Material set of colors, like red, yellow, green, blue, black, transparent, etc. Or you can specify by its HEX color code, like this: `TextStyle(color: Color(0xff**000000**))`. The HEX color always starts with **0xff** followed by the six-digit number of the color.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(new Hello());

class Hello extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new MaterialApp(
      home: new Material(
        child: new Center(
          child: new Text("Hello!", style: TextStyle(color: Colors.indigo)),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Also, with material colors you can give them different shades by specifying their opacity, like `TextStyle(color: Colors.green[600])`